# linux route command not working

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, routing

I use route command to add new route in my routing table. But it my new root is not added. Also it doesn't show any error for my command. Here is the console

```
#route add ::/0 via fe::2
route: resolving fe::2
#
```

So when I use route -A inet6, I can't see the newly added route.

Comment: ... You're trying to add a default route via local-link addresses?

Comment: I don't know about local address. But I want to assign this address,fe80::02d9:98ff:fec1:8eea as default route to my linux machine.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. The correct syntax to add a route is

```
#ip -6 route add <destination> dev <device> via <gateway>
```